# Create Instance using Shared Image on Alibaba Cloud

Tags: cloud, alibaba-cloud, alibaba-cloud-ecs

I'm trying to copy instance from an account to another account. Both of them are in same region. Based on [here](https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/25389.htm?spm=a2c63.p38356.879954.7.31a96889e5q7en#table-hwf-rpj-dhb) I should use **Shared Image**. And now I wanna create that Image by following [this](https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/35109.htm?spm=a2c63.p38356.879954.14.3eaf5b5eX934z7#concept-ech-5bm-xdb). But it have concerns that too risky for me.

- Do not load data disk information to the /etc/fstab directory. Otherwise, instances created from the custom image cannot be started.

How do I can do the point above? Do I can do it from the instance terminal? Because I'm not sure able to do this in Alibaba ECS console.

- We strongly recommended that you umount all the file systems mounted on the Linux instance before creating a custom image. Otherwise, instances created from the custom image may not be started or used.

What is the main risk of this? Because the source instance is contain a live product, I'm affraid it will stop the instance.

I'm sorry if you think that I ask basic question, I've no experience in system and cloud service. Thanks

Comment: The warning is only if you have several disks in the original instance, as the use of a customer image won't enforce the creation of the hardware needed for it to run.
However, if you are not replying on those other Disks for the machine to start things, if should not impact the new one.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a custom image from a running ECS instance does not stop or start the instance. And in relation to the other queries, its all relating to additional disks beyond the system disk. So if for some reason the instance you want to create an image from contains information on data disks in fstab, it would make more sense to create the image anyway, deploy it to a VM, start the copy and remove the fstab references and then create the image from that copy. Hence no impact to your production environment.